# Is “was” used as a modal particle here?

Tags: translation, word-usage, german-to-english

> Dann kann ich jetzt endlich was abarbeiten.

I think I understand this sentence except for the use of *was:*

> Now I can finally work.

But I can’t determine how the *was* changes either the meaning or the tone of the sentence.

Is it a modal particle here? Or does it actually change the meaning from what I think this means?

Comment: Just a general remark... "was" is never a modal particle... it's always either a question word or short for "etwas"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Was* is short for *etwas* (something) here and is the required object for *abarbeiten.* Thus the sentence means

> Now I can finally work some things off.

or more freely:

> Now I can finally get some work done.

Comment: Ah! I'll have to look out for this in the future. I always see `was` as `what`. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In this example, `was` is an abbreviation of `etwas`. So it's a normal object, not a modal particle.

Answer (score 4):

Addition to the given answer: "was" as abbreviation for "etwas" is mainly colloquially used. See also http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/etwas.

In professional writing you should better avoid it (citations and direct speech excluded), if not the overall writing style is colloquial and thus "demands" it.